# VSTO ItemAdd event is not firing

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

I have the following VSTO add-in code. However, the `items_ItemAdd()` method is not getting involked.

```
public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        Outlook.NameSpace outlookNameSpace;
        Outlook.MAPIFolder inbox;
        Outlook.Items items;

        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            outlookNameSpace = this.Application.GetNamespace("MAPI");
            Debug.WriteLine("Starting Add-In");
            inbox = outlookNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(
                    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.
                    OlDefaultFolders.olFolderInbox);
            items = inbox.Items;
            items.ItemAdd +=
                new Outlook.ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler(items_ItemAdd);
            Debug.WriteLine("Started Add-In");
        }

        void items_ItemAdd(object Item)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("New email arrived.");
            Outlook.MailItem mail = (Outlook.MailItem)Item;
            if (Item != null)
            {
                if (mail.MessageClass == "IPM.Note")
                {
                    string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "example.html");
                    Debug.WriteLine("Saving to " + path);
                    mail.SaveAs(path, Outlook.OlSaveAsType.olHTML);
                }
            }
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        #region VSTO generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

This is very similar to the example given in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268998.aspx) Does anyone have an idea? I'm developing this with Visual Studio 2010 using a VSTO Outlook 2007 add-in. Trying this in debug mode but the event isn't firing. I have Outlook 2010 installed on my dev machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get the `ItemsEvents_ItemAddEventHandler` to work despite declaring some members at class level to get around Garbage Collection as that seems to be the only answer suggested everywhere on the internet...

What did work was to add a slight time delay at the time of attaching the event as shown below:

```
System.Threading.Timer timer = null;
timer = new System.Threading.Timer((obj) =>
{
    ItemAddEventHandler();
    timer.Dispose();
}, null, 3000, System.Threading.Timeout.Infinite);
```

I did find `NewMailEx` event to be more reliable but it has it's drawbacks such as unable to choose the folders to 
listen to event on.Hope this helps someone, though it's not a clean solution by any measure.